# Can I use maven to add sources as part of my project?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am using a dependency and I have some issues with it.
I could download the sources and include it as part of my project and then start modifying the source to help me debug my issue.

However, is there an easier way to do this, using maven ? I have the source-jars downloaded but I am not sure if I can then use these source jars and modify the code as well ?

I could in theory unbar the sources and add them to my source build path, but is there an easier way to accomplish this ?

I am using maven and IntelliJ.

Comment: Source jars are essentially read-only until you unpack them and create new projects.  It might be easier to locate the projects source repository and clone it from there - it is most likely a git project.  Then locate the commit that generated the artifact and branch out from there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get a successful build of the dependency you're having issues with (in it's own project?).

If so, change the version, e.g. `1.2.3-CUSTOM-1`, make the improvements, rebuild, and use it as a proper maven depdendency with `<version>1.2.3-CUSTOM-1</version>`.

This might seem a lot of work, but it's not really - you end up with a properly versioned jar.... having a "hacked" version of `1.2.3` jar is asking for all sorts of problems later.

On the plus side, you can share and deploy the `-CUSTOM-1` jar if you need to, and you can keep versioning `-CUSTOM-2`, etc.

This is the "proper way" I would say.

Answer (score 0):

As Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen wrote, source jars are read-only. You can setup debugger breakpoints in them, but you can't "write" in them

1. Either unjar the sourced jar or if you know it came from a git release tag, clone the original repository and checkout the correct tag
2. Make sure its sources compile
3. Bump up the version in case you know you are going to hack the source
4. On the right pane, use Maven projects / Plus icon to add sources and use the "m" Execute goal icon to build the sources in IDEA :

[image]